# How can I force a minimum viewport width and height on iOS Safari, regardless of orientation?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari, viewport

I have a web app that needs to be within a container of a fixed size. I want that container to always be completely visible on the screen of mobile devices. (Particularly I care about iPads.) In my case, the container is 1000px wide by 650px tall. Essentially, I need something that would be the functional equivalent of `<meta name="viewport" content="min-width=1000, min-height=650">`. But `min-width` and `min-height` aren't valid in a viewport meta tag.

I already have the page laid out such that if the window or viewport has extra room the content is displayed centered on the page. I've tried using the `orientationchange` event to change the `content` attribute of my `meta` tag, but no luck. With some configurations that I've tried it loads correctly initially (sometimes, refreshing or reopening the page often yields different results) but upon changing orientation it becomes incorrect.

This is the closest I've come to getting it to work (in the `window.onOrientationChange` event):

```
var mvp = document.getElementById('myViewport');
if(window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight > 1000 / 650) {
    mvp.setAttribute('content',"user-scalable=yes, height=650");
} else {
    mvp.setAttribute('content',"user-scalable=yes, width=1000");
}
```

Where of course `#myViewport` is my viewport meta tag. This works correctly in portrait (although when switching back and forth I have to manually zoom back out,) but doesn't add the extra width needed to zoom out to see the full app height in landscape. Also, I'd prefer not to allow users to zoom in and out because of the nature of the app, and certainly don't want to require them to zoom out every time they change orientation.

If there is a way to force the zoom to always fit to screen, something akin to `minimum-scale=auto, maximum-scale=auto`, it seems like that would work (if I could get the width correct in landscape,) but I don't know of such a mechanism. I also tried using javascript to determine the scale, based on `window.outerHeight` or `window.outerWidth` depending on which one is the determining factor, but that wasn't successful either.

And please don't tell me that this is bad design, because the specs come from the client for their internal-use app and there's nothing I can do about them.

Comment: You mean like `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">`?

Comment: @JeffShaver No, that will make the viewport match the dimensions of the device, which may be more or less than what I need. For example, an iPad in portrait mode reports 768px width, but I would need the viewport to be 1000px width. Basically, the viewport needs to be width >= 1000px and height >= 650px.